# $\{V_n\}$ and $\{W_n\}$ are two sequences of random variables, show that$V_n-W_n\overset{p}\to0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\{V_n\}$ and $\{W_n\}$ be two sequences of random variables satisfying the following conditions.

(i) For all $\delta>0$, there exists $\lambda$ s.t. $P(|W_n|>\lambda)<\delta$.

(ii) For all $k$ and all $\varepsilon>0$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(V_n\le k,W_n\ge k+\varepsilon)=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(V_n\ge k+\varepsilon ,W_n\le k)=0.$$

Then $V_n-W_n\overset{p}\to0$,as $n\to\infty$.

How to understand and prove this proposition?

Comment: Observe that if $V_n \leq k$ and $W_n \geq k + \varepsilon$, it follows that $W_n - V_n \geq \varepsilon$, so that the conditions imply that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(W_n - V_n \geq \varepsilon) = 0$, and similarly $ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(V_n - W_n \geq \varepsilon) = 0$.

Comment: The observation is very helpful. But how to use condition (i). Is it a redundant condition?

Comment: If $V_n = W_n = \infty$, then $V_n - W_n = \infty - \infty$ is not defined, and similarly if $V_n = W_n = - \infty$. However, condition (i) implies that $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} P(|W_n| > \lambda) = 0$, so that in particular, $ P(|W_n| = \infty) = 0 $. We can use this to argue rigorously that the set of values where $V_n - W_n$ is not defined is negligible, and hence does not affect the desired conclusion.

Comment: Unless you say how $k$ is chosen the arguments in above comments are not valid.

Comment: Does condition (i) holds for some/all $n$?

Comment: I think it holds for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments. I find a proof in the book *Order Statistics* by David and Nagaraja (2003) on page 286.

Fix $\varepsilon>0, \delta>0$, by condtion (i) we can choose integers $m$ and $n_0$ s.t.
$$P(|W_n|>m\varepsilon)<\delta,\quad for~~~ n\ge n_0.$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
P(|V_n&-W_n|>2\varepsilon)<\delta+P(|W_n|\le m\varepsilon,|V_n-W_n|>2\varepsilon)\\
&=\delta+\sum_{j=-m}^{m-1}P(j\varepsilon\le W_n\le (j+1)\varepsilon,|V_n-W_n|>2\varepsilon)\\
&\le\delta+\sum_{j=-m}^{m-1}\Big[P\Big(j\varepsilon\le W_n\le (j+1)\varepsilon,V_n>(j+2)\varepsilon\Big)\\
&+P\Big(j\varepsilon\le W_n\le (j+1)\varepsilon,V_n<(j-1)\varepsilon\Big)\Big]
\end{align*} 
which tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ by condtion (ii).